# Mockito mock static method of class, but other instance methods of same class should not be mocked instead it must be called normally

Tags: java, testing, mockito, static-methods, instance-methods

I have class let say ABC.
In this class there is static method `public static void staticOne(){...}`
In same class there are non-static methods also present let say `method1() method2()`.

In mockito I want to write test case for `method1()` in which static method staticOne is being called and I want to mock it.
So how can I do that ?

I am using mockito version 4.11.0.
Can I have solution for this problem using only mockito ?

=============================================================

```
class ABC {

public void static staticOne(){
...
}

public string method1(){
staticOne();
...
}

}
```

how can I write test case for `method1()` while mocking staticOne

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible, I wouldn't recommend it. There might be a way to refactor and split the static method out into a util class.

If it's not possible you can use `MockStatic` and afterwards create an instance :

```
MockedStatic<ABC> staticABC = Mockito.mockStatic(ABC.class);
... // define operations on mock
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.method1();
... // assertions
```

I added an example in this [repository](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-mock-static-method)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad the issue is resolved.